# Groovy - Read JSON value using variable

Tags: json, variables, groovy

I'm new to groovy & json but did a bit of reading on these topic. I have a request where to read a json property value using a variable. Here is the example with the code i am using:

```
String vari = 'location'; // works
String vari = 'location.link';//doesnt work

def apiResp = '{"result":{"calendar_integration":"1","country":"CA","last_position_update":"","user_password":"$s$tHkpjt3a","u_alarm_vendor":"","last_login_time":"2019-08-28 22:16:23","location":{"link":"adata-test.co.com","value":"4a5595aaf8905100af662979a41c880c"},"u_pos_qty":"10"}}';

jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(apiResp);

String fldVal = jsonSlurper.result[vari];
println(fldVal);
```

The need for using a variable 'vari' is to accept the inputs from a sub-process and return the relevant value. For instance, one subprocess call will have 'last_login_time' mapped to the variable 'vari' and other call will have 'location.link' mapped. So considering this, i thought of coming up a generic groovy that addresses this requirement. However mapping 'last_login_time' works and provides the required data but not 'location.link', returns null

May i request for some help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible to access json by dynamic path using [Eval.me](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html#me(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String))

```
import groovy.json.*
String vari = 'ROOT.result.location.link'

def apiResp = '{"result":{"calendar_integration":"1","country":"CA","last_position_update":"","user_password":"$s$tHkpjt3a","u_alarm_vendor":"","last_login_time":"2019-08-28 22:16:23","location":{"link":"adata-test.co.com","value":"4a5595aaf8905100af662979a41c880c"},"u_pos_qty":"10"}}'

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(apiResp)
String fldVal = Eval.me('ROOT',jsonSlurper,vari)
```